# "I had my lunch" vs. "I ate my lunch"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, british-english, collocations

Between the following, which is acceptable/preferable and why?

> - I had my lunch.
> - I ate my lunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are acceptable, and both can mean that the speaker had eaten a lunch. Because *had* is a versatile word with several meanings, though, "I had my lunch" can also be used in other contexts, where it means something different. For example:

> Sarah asked if I wanted to go with her to get lunch in the cafeteria, but **I had my lunch**.
>
> > (In other words, *I had brought my own lunch from home*.)
>
> My wife saw my lunchbox on the countertop, so she called to ask if **I had my lunch**.
>
> > (In other words, *Did I have my lunch with me? Or did I inadvertently leave it at home?*)

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical, but might be found in different contexts. As both use a verb in the past tense, they both refer to the eating of lunch at a particular time in the past, and would usually continue with some further elaboration.